# How can you run a python script as a batch job after passing an argument using argparse?

Tags: python, bash, batch-file, argparse

I was wondering whether it is possible to run a python script as a bash job after using argparse? I tried doing this by first passing an argument in the python script file using argparse and then I used the command:

```
bash bash1.sh
```

to run the bash file that will run the python script file. This resulted in an error

```
message_script.py: error: too few arguments
```

This error resulted from the fact that the argparse argument wasn't recognised. Is there any way I can get to pass the argument using argparse then run the python script as a batch job?

Content of message_script.py:

```
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import argparse
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Input of Data File
#Proprtion Alpha
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("Alpha", help = "proportion of pixels to be embedded in cover image")
args = parser.parse_args()
alpha = args.Alpha
alpha = float(alpha) #args.alpha came back as a string hence needed to be converted to float

#n is the number of pixels in cover image
n = 512*512 #since all images in BossBase testbench are 512 by 512

#Length of message to be embedded in cover image
length_msg = (alpha * n)
len_msg = int(length_msg)

#Generates a random message, a 1D vector consisting of 1s and 0s
msg = np.random.randint(2, size= len_msg)

#Save message in text format representing each bit as 0 or 1 on a separate line
msg_text_file = open("/home/ns3/PycharmProjects/untitled1/msg_file.txt", "w") #Path of Data File
msg_text_file.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), msg)))
msg_text_file .close()
```

Content of bash1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python message_script.py
```

Comment: Can you please share more details? what does you willing to achieve? can you share the content of bash1.sh and message_script.py ?

Comment: judging by what is already known, the bash script does not pass the arguments over. could you post the bash script?

Comment: @MosheZada I just attached the contents of the message_script.py and bash file bash1.sh. With the python script I am creating a text file and the bash file is simply running that python script to create the text file.

Comment: @3k- I also posted the bash script

Comment: The script does not retain any memory of `alpha` between the time you ran it alone and when you run it as batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass along the arguments to the python script. If you know the exact number of your arguments you can write smth like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# passing two arguments
python message_script.py "$1" "$2"
```

Or all of them:

```
#!/bin/bash
python message_script.py "$@"
```

Comment: I did that when passing it in the command line and it worked. I did python message_script.py 0.5 but after that I did  bash bash1.sh and it gave me this error:     usage: message_script.py [-h] Alpha
message_script.py: error: too few arguments @3k-

Comment: @CharlesB so you have something like `python message_script.py 0.5` in the bash script?

Comment: @CharlesB you could also add a keyword argument to `add_argument` `type=float` so you can spare casting the value

Comment: python message_script.py 0.5 was inputted in the command terminal of ubuntu @ 3k-

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. if you have a bash script like above then `./bash1.sh 0.5` should definitely work. above that you can also put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your python script, make it executable using `chmod a+x message_script.py` and you could execute it directly like `./message_script.py 0.5`