# nohup: ignoring input, but my python program DOES require input

Tags: python, linux, terminal, background, nohup

train.py is a python program that parses the input variables using argparse, and should
run in the background without an attached terminal, but invariably the input is ignored. I tested the following options:

`/home/workspace# nohup /home/workspace/train.py vgg19 3000 1 cpu &`

and

`nohup /home/workspace/doit &`

where `doit` is a script containing

`/home/workspace/train.py vgg19 3000 1 cpu`

which all result in:

`home/workspace# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

The only workaround that works (yet not acceptable for my project) is to hard-code the input variables in the python program and use :

`nohup python -u ./train_LONG.py &`

Moreover, which is super confusing, even the following command results in input being ignored:

`nohup ./train_LONG.py -u &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken about what the error message means. It relates to standard input, not command-line arguments.

For the record, to run a process which needs to read standard input with `nohup`, add a redirection.

```
nohup yourprogram <file &
```

or with a here document

```
nohup yourprogram <<\HERE &
first line of input
second line of input
etc
HERE
```

or with a pipe

```
nohup printf '%s\n' "first line of input" "second line of input" etc |
yourprogram &
```

Comment: thank you all; I finally got the application to do what I need https://1drv.ms/b/s!AstWh2CO-Hmwii-IGOj1Ij24pdpl?e=c4SDcY

Comment: It's unclear what the link is supposed to demonstrate. If you want to share a solution, a site which doesn't require JavaScript would probably be better. But posting your answer here as a separate answer is better still.

Comment: I posted the link to my report because I could not add much detail in the 'add comment' box

Comment: I'ld say it again: post an answer of your own if you think that information is useful. I was able to click through but the content was pretty much unreadable so I gave up at that point.

Answer (score 0):

[Nohup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) does not take input from stdin. The best option for passing in inputs while running within nohup is getting input through command line arguments using libraries like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html). There are alternatives like using network for input or using other utilities like [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), but command-line arguments are generally easier to work with if you're working with applications that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me is as follows:

1. Build a script `do_script`
2. submit the script `nohup /home/workspace/do_script &`

where `do_script` is

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    python -u /home/workspace/train.py vgg19  8000 15  cuda
```

Step # 1 above was decisive; it was proposed for a [different application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819254/how-can-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-batch-job-after-passing-an-argument-using-a) with similar requirements.
Moreover, at the beginning of this work I saw no output in the log file: [this blog](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-background/) made be aware that the  -u flag helps avoiding output buffering.
As a result the application survives across workspace disconnects and collects all relevant outputs in the log file